# How to make div with background image responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the following part of my website responsive.

[image]

I tried to make one div image responsive but it didn't work.

```
<div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-4 main_service main_auto">
                       <h4>
                        <a title="Automotive" href="searchcat1.aspx?cat=Automotive">Automotive</a></h4>
                    <p>
                        <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Auto Spare Parts">Auto 
                        Spare Parts</a>
                         <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Commercial Vehicles">
                        Commercial Vehicles</a> 
                         <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Oil value Lubricants">
                        Oil value Lubricants</a>
                          <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Tyres and Batteries">
                        Tyres and Batteries</a> 
                          <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Automotive Tools">
                        Automotive Tools</a> 
                          <span class="right"><a href="searchcat1.aspx?cat=Automotive">more ...</a></span></p>
                   </div>
               </div>
```

I am new to Bootstrap.

Comment: Please make a JsFiddle with your code for the whole section

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 main_service main_auto">
                       <h4>
                        <a title="Automotive" href="searchcat1.aspx?cat=Automotive">Automotive</a></h4>
                    <p>
                        <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Auto Spare Parts">Auto 
                        Spare Parts</a>
                         <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Commercial Vehicles">
                        Commercial Vehicles</a> 
                         <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Oil value Lubricants">
                        Oil value Lubricants</a>
                          <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Tyres and Batteries">
                        Tyres and Batteries</a> 
                          <a title="" href="searchsubcat.aspx?cat=Automotive&subcat=Automotive Tools">
                        Automotive Tools</a> 
                          <span class="right"><a href="searchcat1.aspx?cat=Automotive">more ...</a></span></p>
                   </div>
               </div>
```